# Download PDF in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm downloading PDF files with selenium and firefox.

I'm facing problems because right after downloading the pdf the file opens in the browser. How can I download the pdf and not open it in the browser?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    self.options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    self.options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
    self.options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
    self.options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
    self.firefox = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
    self.firefox.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include the options in driver instantiation statement:

```
self.firefox = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()), options = self.options)
```